# How to add a second key-binding to execute-extended command in emacs OS X

Tags: emacs, alias, init

I'm aware that bash allows a user to make aliases to simplify commands, however, I've been told that something like this is possible for emacs as well. I'm not sure if this is true or not because I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it by searching the web.

For example, I am trying to make a second key-binding for `M-x`, but I'm not sure if its even possible. I assume you must add some code to the `~/.emacs` init file.

If someone can point me in the right direction, or provide an example, that would be more than adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [a few different ways to bind keys in Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html), but if you simply want to add a second global keybinding for `execute-extended-command` you can use `global-set-key`, e.g.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f10>") 'execute-extended-command)
```

`F10` should now do the same as `M-x`.